# Esconde log de error PHP

Tags: php

Estou acessando um PHP de uma aplicação, faço isso com *ajax*, porém quero ter controle de todo erro emitido, ou seja, não quero que o *php* retorne o erro para mim.

Tentei utilizar

```php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );
```

Porém não tive resultado algum. O erro está sendo lançado no *console* do aplicativo em que utilizo para acessar.

Como fazer isto?
Em meu código retirei todos os `echos`, `print_r` e outros que da algum retorno de erro.

Comment: Como está configurado a exibição dos erros no php.ini?

Comment: Qual erro aparece no console do navegador?

Comment: consegui resolver, bastou alterar o displayy_erros = off

Comment: Em qual arquivo você está colocando o `error_reporting()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procure no seu `php.ini` e altere de

> display_errors = on

para

> display_errors = off